# The simplest way to keep n-channel mosfet saturated by positive feedback

Tags: mosfet, positive-feedback

Actully it will be one way switch for a lamp based on photo-resistor input:
[image]

To keep the mosfet saturated in the moment it turns on I need positive feedback. How to get it in the simplest way? I can think only about this option below, but is it the simplest solution?

[image]

Comment: Have you considered using an SCR?

Comment: you will likely need a 2nd active component of some sort. maybe a depletion mode fet could work, not used one for this before...

Comment: @vir SCR/thyristor looks like exactly what I need. Thank you, will try it

Comment: Be clear on how to turn a thyristor OFF...

Comment: When a bjt is fully "on" it is said to be "saturated". However, just to be perverse, someone decided that a MOSFET is "saturated" when it is in the region where an increase in Vds does not result in an increase in Id. I.e. what for a BJT would be called the active region. So, do you want your MOSFET to be "saturated" or in the "Ohmic" region?